# Do we have any evidence or research on the linguistic evolution of idioms?

Tags: evolution, evolutionary-linguistics, idiomaticity

Do we have any evidence or research on the linguistic evolution of idioms?

For example, if two languages in the same language family have idioms with a similar meaning, is it likely that such an idiom was present in the proto or parent language of this family? Have any such reconstructions been done?

Or, is it more usual that one of the languages borrowed the idiom from another language after they were completely separate languages?

Comment: What about likewise emergence and evolution within a given language?

Comment: An example of what you seem to describe is Indo-European stock phrases. The reference book on them is How to Kill a Dragon by Calvert Waltkins. Some examples are [here](http://i.imgur.com/ytDB1S3.png)